# Disable polling of DVD Drive - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, udisks

My DVD Drive constantly clicks every couple of seconds.

Through other forums I found that this has to do with polling for which there existed a solution with udisks:
udisks --inhibit-polling /dev/sr0

udisks is no longer available for Ubuntu 22.04 and udisks2 does not have this functionality.

Does anyone have an up-to-date fix for that?